# Linked in Oauth log in exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm attempting to get the user id from a user who logged in using Linked it.

I can get logged in and get a access token. But my try statement below fails and gives me this exception "System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented."

Any advice how i can get the user id?

```
try
                {

                    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id)?oauth2_access_token=" + access_token + "&format=json", ""));
                    request.ContentType = "application/json";
                    request.Method = "GET";
                    var user_ID = values["user_id"];

                    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                    {
                        System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Stautus Code is: {0}", response.StatusCode);

                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
                            {

                                System.Console.Out.WriteLine(content);
                            }
                           var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception exx)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(exx.ToString());
                }
```

Log in function that works.

```
 var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId: "MYID",
            clientSecret: "SECret",
            scope: "r_basicprofile",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri("http://adults.wicareerpathways.org/"),
            accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken")
        );

        auth.AllowCancel = true;
        auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {
            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                string dd = eventArgs.Account.Username;
                var values = eventArgs.Account.Properties;
                var access_token = values["access_token"];
               // var user_ID = values["user_id"];
                if (linkedinLoginCompleted != null)
                {
                    var LinkedInAccount = new Mobile.LinkedIn.Account
                    {
                        Username = eventArgs.Account.Username,
                        Properties = eventArgs.Account.Properties

                    };

                    linkedinLoginCompleted(LinkedInAccount);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin lists Dynamic code generation as a limitation in it's documentation:

> Since the iPhone's kernel prevents an application from generating code
>   dynamically Mono on the iPhone does not support any form of dynamic
>   code generation. These include:
>
> The System.Reflection.Emit is not available. No support for
>   System.Runtime.Remoting. No support for creating types dynamically (no
>   Type.GetType ("MyType`1")), although looking up existing types
>   (Type.GetType ("System.String") for example, works just fine). Reverse
>   callbacks must be registered with the runtime at compile time.

Source: [Xamarin Limitations](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/)

You can deserialize to a specific type and it should solve the issue.